# Python: proper usage when coding an oop, windowed app

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, window

I'm currently writing a tiny windowed app using python and `tkinter`.

I have very little experience with `tkinter` and I asked myself whether it would be best to:

- make my window a class inheriting from `tkinter.Tk`
- initialise all objects and variables
- do all the processes in its `__init__` method as if it was a `main` likewise:

  ```
  class Main_Frame(tkinter.Tk):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()
          self.grid = Grid(60, 40)
          can_width, can_height = self.canvas_dim()
          self.can = tk.Canvas(self, width = can_width, height = can_height)
          self.can.bind('<Button-1>', self.color_1)
          self.can.pack()
  ```

Also, all the functions would be translated to become methods of that class.

Or should I just instantiate the `Tk` class and put all treatments, variables and instances in the `main`?

If you need a more detailed look on the code here are the two versions of the code: [gist](https://gist.github.com/LouisonCalbrix/50eaa8ab58f883d4b3878a3f80e7c9d7)

Comment: This is either _primarily opinion based_ or a duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17466561/7032856) IMO.

Comment: i agree this is primarily opinion based, personally i prefer putting all methods relating to the GUI into a single class that inherits from a tk widget. as this keeps related code together.

Comment: I tend to put all the GUI into one class and inherit from frame.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to inherit from `tkinter.Tk` as that object needs to be _singularly present_, hence it breaks object reuse. I think `Frame` is the better option here. You can manipulate the Tk object anyway using `widget.winfo_toplevel()` anyway.

Comment: @Nae thanks for your suggestions! I have read some related questions (a lot of which were answered by Bryan Oakley) that helped me very much.

Comment: While this isn't what you asked, I recommend creating the GUI in another method and other variables not related to the GUI In `__init__`.  This allows you to separate GUI from class code and makes things easy to  differentiate.